# How do i get the value of maximum used rows in a excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I used the below mentioned code ,but it returns the count of rows including the unused code

```
maxrows = sheet.max_row
print maxrows
```

i get 1048026 as the value but the used rows are only 278

Comment: I'm guessing you're using openpyxl? Then `sheet.max_row` should work. Perhaps that cell isn't really empty (any kind of formatting change, perhaps?). See also https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/514/cell-max_row-reports-higher-than-actual

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
maxrows = sheet.nrows
print maxrows